# Per-site metas are not linked properly from the Data Explorer

Tags: bug, data-explorer, per-site-meta

I was looking through my results from [this cross-site query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/330763/find-all-my-unaccepted-question-network-wide) when I noticed that the results for the questions I asked on the Arqade meta pointed to `http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/<####>` instead of `http://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/<####>` as expected.

I wouldn't have noticed this error, had it not been for the fact that the Arqade main site is blocked by a work filter, but ever since the change to `site.meta...` from `meta.site...`, I've been able to access the Arqade meta.

Comment: Arghhhhhhhhhhhhhh, yeah, I didn't even consider this. I think there's some logic in there somewhere that relies on the prior domain arrangement too |:

Comment: You should blame the creator of that query ... which happens to be me ... I'm looking into this and will answer.

Comment: @rene Not sure it's actually your fault...

Comment: Or at least not entirely your fault.

Comment: Well, we can blame Nick for the meta move ...

Comment: Looking a little closer at the query, if I'm understanding the `#siteurl` procedure correctly, it's reversing the order of the `name` column in the `sys.databases` table, using a dot as the delimiter.  So the format for that column just needs to be changed to `StackExchange.Meta.Site`.  No big deal, right?

Comment: @MBraedley yeah, that is it. I'm working on a replacement of that procedure.

Comment: @rene: [Here's something that seems to work](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/713933/my-user-id-on-all-se-sites), even if it's not as tidy as yours. That trick you're using with `parsename()` looks useful; I may want to try stealing it. (I kind of suck at T-SQL, in case you can't tell.) Unfortunately the lack of redirects for per-site metas of renamed sites makes having a bunch of special cases kind of inevitable (and I'm not even sure I've found all the sites that need them yet).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sorry that you have run into a bug on one of my queries and is caused by the recent switch of the meta domain names (from meta.[sitename] to [sitename].meta) to support https.

As multi-db query-ing is not formally supported in the public SEDE version the magic link generation for the urls will not work and therefor I relied on the databasename to generate the site url. It was a simple split by dot and reverse.

As that is no longer feasible I will update that query with a new version of the #siteurl procedure

```sql
-- create url based on dbname
create procedure #siteurl
   @dbname nvarchar(250),
   @res nvarchar(250) OUT
   as
   begin
      if @dbname = 'StackExchange.Meta' 
      begin
        set @res = 'Meta.StackExchange'
      end
      else
      begin
        declare @p1 nvarchar(250) = parsename(@dbname,1)
        declare @p2 nvarchar(250) = parsename(@dbname,2)
        declare @p3 nvarchar(250) = parsename(@dbname,3)

        set @res = 
          (case when @p1 = 'Meta' then @p2 else @p1 end) + 
          (case when @p2 is null then '' else '.' end) +
          (case when @p1 = 'Meta' then @p1 else isnull(@p2,'') end) +
          (case when @p3 is null then '' else '.' end) +
          isnull(@p3,'')     
      end;
   end;
go
```

This procedure will output the following for a given input (input > output)

> ```
> StackExchange.Expressionengine.Meta > Expressionengine.Meta.StackExchange
> StackExchange.Expressionengine > Expressionengine.StackExchange
> Stackoverflow > Stackoverflow
> ```

which seems about right.

I have gone ahead and updated the query you used. It should render the correct urls for you.

Thanks for reporting.