# SEDE generates incorrect links for localized Stack Overflow Metas

Tags: bug, data-explorer, per-site-meta, international-sites

Stack Exchange Data Explorer generates wrong (outdated) links for localized child metas

[Example query on Stack Overflow em Portugues Meta](https://data.stackexchange.com/ptme/query/1070769/some-random-posts) generates this url:

> https://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1

But [in 2017 child metas were moved to *.meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time). The correct link would be:

> [Aqui NÃO É o stackoverflow.com](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1)

At the same time SEDE generates correct links for regular StackExchange child metas (e.g. [Politics Meta](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.politics/query/1070769/some-random-posts)). I suppose, someone forgot to update the url in [DataExplorer]..[Sites] for international StackOverflows.

Until recently, old subdomains redirected traffic successfully, but now certificates have expired and old-style urls generate SSL errors.

This is a minor annoyance, but it'd be great to see it fixed. It shouldn't be hard, as base urls are retrieved from the `Sites` table somewhere in the database.

**Update:** This question was marked as a duplicate of [Per-site metas are not linked properly from the Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298517/per-site-metas-are-not-linked-properly-from-the-data-explorer). That question is about the problem with a link generation in a particular cross-site query (written by @rene).

My question is about the base url for automatically generated links (triggered by [Post Link]). As I show it generates the correct url for regular child metas ([Politics](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.politics/query/1070769/some-random-posts)), but fails for localized Stack Overflow metas ([Pt.SO](https://data.stackexchange.com/ptme/query/1070769/some-random-posts)). The issue is completely different here.

The solution ([fix by @rene](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298521/151960)) posted there doesn't apply here. I know that I can generate the url myself, but it'd be nice to use the shortcut that works for any other site.

Comment: @Glorfindel Sorry, I don't see how this is a duplicate. I've updated my question.

Comment: You're right, it's [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305185/295232) which didn't have the tags I was searching in. I just knew that this was reported before.

Comment: @Glorfindel Yes, that's correct. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome and sorry for the confusion ...

Comment: ... and irony has it - it turns out I've warned another user about this difference before: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305185/alias-post-link-in-data-stackexchange-com-generate-invalid-links-for-meta-sit#comment991958_305185